# Rails: NameError (uninitialized constant UserSerializer)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, serialization, fastjsonapi

I am currently building a Rails API-only application using Rails 6.0. I am using [fast_jsonapi](https://github.com/Netflix/fast_jsonapi) for JSON:API serialization of Ruby Objects. For now I have created only the `UsersController`.

I have a `user` model with the following attributes:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2020_03_14_175719) do
 create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "first_name"
    t.string "last_name"
    t.string "username"
    t.string "password_digest"
    t.string "email"
    t.string "phone"
    t.text "address"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["username"], name: "index_users_on_username", unique: true
  end
end
```

I have created a `user_serializer` for it:

```
class UserSerializer
  include FastJsonapi::ObjectSerializer
  attributes :first_name, :last_name, :username, :password, :email, :phone, :address
end
```

I have also created a `User` on the database via the `rails console` with the following information:

```
User.delete_all
user = User.create! first_name: 'Promise', last_name: 'My last name', username: 'myusername', email: 'myemail@gmail.com', password: 'mypassword', phone: '002037363', address: 'my address'
puts "Created a new user: #{user.first_name} #{user.last_name} with email - #{user.email}"
```

However, when I run the command below in the rails console:

```
UserSerializer.new(User.first).serializable_hash
```

I get the error below:

> NameError (uninitialized constant UserSerializer)

I have tried a few solutions, but none seems to be working. I need some help. Thanks.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

**Here's how I solved it**:

Exit the rails console, if you're still inside it:

```
exit
```

Stop the [spring](https://github.com/rails/spring) Rails application preloader:

```
spring stop
```

Enter `rails console` in development environment again:

```
rails console
```

Run the command again:

```
UserSerializer.new(User.first).serializable_hash
```

It gives an output of this sort:

```
#<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<User id: 3, first_name: "Promise", last_name: "My last name", username: "myusername", password_digest: [FILTERED], email: "myemail@gmail.com", phone: "002037363", address: "my address", created_at: "2020-03-14 18:36:31", updated_at: "2020-03-14 18:36:31">]>
```

That's all.

**I hope this helps**

Comment: Worked like a charm, Thank ya.

Answer (score 1):

Reload the terminal source or starting a new terminal tab will also work.
Opening a new **terminal** and starting a new `rails console` worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try `reload!` in rails console.

You can also open `rails console` in another `tab` or `terminal`.