# JsonApi Serializer Not Found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, active-model-serializers, jsonapi-serialize

I have run `gem 'jsonapi-serializer'` and `bundle install`.

I then try to run a generator `rails g serializer User username id` but the command always freezes. So I created the serializer manually:

```rb
# app/serializers/user_serializer.rb
class UserSerializer
  include JSONAPI::Serializer
  attributes :username, :id
end
```

but when I call it from my `UsersController` I get an error:

```rb
# app/controllers/user_controller.rb
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def show
    render json: { user: UserSerializer.new(User.new(username: 'joe'))}
  end
end
```

here the error:

```html
NameError in UsersController#show
uninitialized constant UsersController::UserSerializer
```

It seems that the UserSerializer is not loading, and I am not sure where I can tinker to make that work.

Answer (score -1):

I think it was a problem with the **spring loader**.

I found this solution to work for me:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/60688929/3755529